Changing the permanent delegate of a token mint?
I’m using the Permanent Delegate extension of the Token-2022 Program. Is there any method to change the permanent delegate? Or to remove it entirely? I’m trying to get a sense for how permanent this delegate really is so that I can decide if I want to build with it.

Only the permanent delegate may change the permanent delegate on a mint.
spl-token authorize <MINT> permanent-delegate <NEW_PERMANENT_DELEGATE>

More info at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#permanent-delegate

Closing and recreating a token account does not affect the associated token accounts, but the new account must be reconfigured, and references to the old account will no longer be valid.

The Permanent Delegate in Token-2022 cannot be changed or removed, except by closing and recreating the token account.

You bring up an interesting solution. If I closed it and recreated it, would anything happen to the underlying associated token accounts?

Closing and recreating a token account does not affect the associated token accounts, but the new account must be reconfigured, and references to the old account will no longer be valid.
